# Insert blob into a input file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to insert a blob to an input file? I have on my website an input file where the user uploads a image. Then a preview of his image is display on my website, and the customer can edit this image. That image is a canvas that i convert then to blob.

So i need to insert this blob to the same input file where the customer has upload his file. Is there any solution for this? 
Hope you can help me!

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to manipulate the actual binary data assigned to an `<input type="file">` as the [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) is immutable. You can however append your modified data to a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object and submit that via AJAX

Comment: But indeed, @Phil is correct, all you need is `FormData.append(yourInput.name, yourBlob, yourInput.files[0].name)` and send your request through AJAX.